# Retrieve last node in list for further processing

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I trying to set up a scheme for web-clicks, where each node is a `(:Click)`, which links to the click that precedes it by a `[:PREV]`-edge and the `(:Session)` that owns it by a `[:GEN]`-edge. In the end this should happen procedural, a new transaction/insert when a new click is made. While I have no problem generating the involved objects, I cannot figure out how to dynamically select last `(:Click)` and link it to the current created one.

Generate a session with 2 clicks:

```
CREATE (s:Session {name:'S0'})
CREATE (c1:Click {name:'C1', click:1}), (c1)<-[:GEN]-(s)
CREATE (c2:Click {name:'C2', click:2}), (c2)<-[:GEN]-(s), (c1)<-[:PREV]-(c2);
```

generate one other click in separated transaction:

```
MERGE (s:Session {name:'S0'})
CREATE (c3:Click {name:'C3', click:3}),
(c3)<-[:GEN]-(s) //(c2)<-[:PREV]-(c3);
```

for the commented out link, I cannot use the `c2`-variable as it is scope-local to the previous transaction.

Now I thought to try something like this to dynamically find the last generated node on the same session and link it

```
MERGE (s:Session {name:'S0'})
CREATE (c3:Click {name:'C3', click:3}), (c3)<-[:GEN]-(s)

MATCH (s)-[:GEN]->(c_prevs:Click) 
WITH c_prevs
ORDER BY c_prevs.click DESC LIMIT 1
CREATE (head(c_prevs))<-[:PREV]-(c3)
```

Unfortunately this won't work for me with any Cypher-construct I came up with so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question to be the following

```
MATCH (s:Session {name:'S0'})
CREATE (c3:Click {name:'C3', click:3})

WITH s, c3
MATCH (s)-[:GEN]->(c_prev:Click) 
WITH c_prev, c3, s
ORDER BY c_prev.click DESC LIMIT 1
WITH c_prev, c3, s
CREATE (c_prev)<-[:PREV]-(c3), (c3)<-[:GEN]-(s)
```

which is chaining through the nodes as variables `s`, `c3` and `last_c` with the `WITH` keyword. Unfortunately this involves a lot of repetition, as every `WITH` in principle is a part-separator in the query, so I learned.

This also allows to carry over already MERGED/CREATED nodes, which might help to ensure their existence.

EDIT:

This problem seems to be even more complicated if clicks should be generated prozedural, thus using one cypher-statement to insert and link any click.

my solution looks like the following

```
MERGE (s:Session {name: $session_name})
WITH s
CREATE (c:Click {name: $click_name, click: $click_count})

WITH s, c
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:GEN]->(c_prev:Click) 
WITH c_prev, c, s
ORDER BY c_prev.click DESC LIMIT 1
WITH c_prev, c, s
FOREACH (o IN CASE WHEN c_prev IS NOT NULL THEN ['1'] ELSE [] END |
  CREATE (c_prev)<-[:PREV]-(c)
)

WITH s, c 
CREATE (c)<-[:GEN]-(s)
```

with executing this statement for `{$session_name, $click_name, $click_count} =[{'AAA', 'C1', 1}, {'AAA', 'C2', 2}, {'AAA', 'C3', 3}]`.

Notice that I had to work around the returning empty node-list by explicitly catching this condition and then not executing the subsequent connection statement with the `FOREACH`-loop on an empty list. This does not only look very ugly, I sincerely think there should be a better way to expressively specify this desired behavior through Cypher in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you can get the last `:Click` node on the same session this way:

```
match (:Session {name:'S0'})-[:GEN]->(c:Click)
where not (:Click)-[:PREV]->(c)
return c
```

That is: Get the node from the same session that does not have an incoming `[PREV]` relationship. Will return `c2`

```
╒═══════════════════════╕
│"c"                    │
╞═══════════════════════╡
│{"name":"C2","click":2}│
└───────────────────────┘
```

For your specific case a query like the following should work:

```
merge (s:Session {name:'S0'})

with s

match (s)-[:GEN]->(last:Click)
where not (:Click)-[:PREV]->(last)

create (c3:Click {name:'C3', click:3}),
(c3)<-[:GEN]-(s),
(last)<-[:PREV]-(c3)
```

Comment: I don't like the logic of this Cypher. The merge at the start implies that the session may not have been created, but if it is created, the following match will match nothing, clearing everything so that no work is done after that point. Session should either exist, and this Cypher enforce that rule, or is should use the ON MATCH/ON CREATE clauses to handle the base case.

Comment: I will accept this answer as it solves my specific question; However, as also suggested by Tezra, it should be possible to create a cypher that retrieves the last node from a ordered list (retrieving [:GEN]-connected nodes to session, order by click property) and then manipulate it. I would be interested how the syntax for that thing would look like.